# How to set default className in react router link changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have menu component , and I checked for active class with current `location.path` that set in `state` . If current url is `localhost/News` , the li with `News` must have `active` class and I done it. But I want to set default **active class** to li first child in **isActive function** if url is `localhost` only !! How can I achieve it ?

```
render() {
  const menu = ['Home','News','Technology']

  const isActive = (name) => (      
    this.state.activeName === '/' + name ? 'active' : ''
  )

  return (
    <nav>
      <div className="nav-wrapper light-blue lighten-1 row">
        <ul id="nav-mobile" className="hide-on-med-and-down col m10">
          {
            menu.map((i) => (
              <li className={isActive(i)} key={i}><a href={'/'+i}>{i}</a></li>
            ))
          }
        </ul>
        <a href="#" className="col m2 right-align">Logo</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if activeName is just `/` and if so return active for the first index like

```
render() {
  const menu = ['Home','News','Technology']

  const isActive = (name, index) => {
    if(this.state.activeName === '/') {
        return index === 0? 'active' : ''
    }     
    return this.state.activeName === '/' + name ? 'active' : ''
  }

  return (
    <nav>
      <div className="nav-wrapper light-blue lighten-1 row">
        <ul id="nav-mobile" className="hide-on-med-and-down col m10">
          {
            menu.map((i, index) => (
              <li className={isActive(i, index)} key={i}><a href={'/'+i}>{i}</a></li>
            ))
          }
        </ul>
        <a href="#" className="col m2 right-align">Logo</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
  )
}
```

Comment: Updated the answer, please check. Basically you need to use explicit return in isActive method

Comment: okay great ! I think return is missing at the bottom line . Anyway Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your component with react-router `withRouter` HOC which will inject location props. Then you can check if `this.props.location` contains 'localhost'

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md